# I am getting a 'not all code paths return a value' error in my c# code

Tags: c#, methods, compiler-errors, return-value

I have written a c# extension method that returns any duplicate values in an array of ints and it is telling me that 'not all code paths return a value'. Here is my code:

```
public static int? FindDuplicate(this int[] arrayToFindDuplicateIn)
    {

        int previousint = int.MaxValue;
        arrayToFindDuplicateIn = arrayToFindDuplicateIn.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray();

        foreach (int number in arrayToFindDuplicateIn)
        {
            if (number == previousint)
            {
                return number;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

            previousint = number;
        }
    }
```

Comment: add return statement after foreach loop ends.

Comment: your foreach loop will end in first time since number ! = previousint (which is int.maxvalue) and will return null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is to remove your else return null; and put the return null; outside your foreach. Otherwise it will only loop once everytime.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is empty, no value is returned, so just return something at the end or check the input array with arrayToFindDuplicateIn.Any()

Comment: I am not checking if the array is empty.